# Simulate low memory for .NET application

Tags: .net, memory, configuration

Sometimes when I am solving problems from Leetcode and I have inefficient solution I am getting an error on LeetCode

> Runtime Error Message: Out of memory.

I would like to be able to reproduce this error in my local development environment.

I've seen some advices such as running the tests from the virtual machine with very limited RAM in settings but I find such approach undesirable.

Ideally I should be able to configure somehow in `App.config`, `runtimeconfig.template.json` or even in my code to set a hard limit, such as the app is not allowed to use more than 1MB of memory. Honestly, I don't know exactly how much memory I should configure as LeetCode documentation doesn't expose this information.

But so far I could not find a working way to put the hard limit

`System.GC.HeapHardLimit` [setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/garbage-collector) seems to be promising but I could not make it work

I created `runtimeconfig.template.json`

```json
{
  "configProperties": {
    "System.GC.HeapHardLimit": 1
  }
}
```

So I allowed the app to use only one byte of heap. But the following code runs without any limitations.

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(0, 1_000_000).Select(_ => new object()).ToArray().Length);
```

I am pretty sure than one million instances of object consume way more than one byte of RAM.

Can anyone explain what am I missing?